# Check if a Binary Tree is full

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, complexity

#### Problem statement

Given a node check whether the sub-tree rooted at given node is full binary tree or not.

#### Definition

> A full binary tree (sometimes proper binary tree or 2-tree) is a tree in which every node other than the leaves has two children.

#### Solution

```
class TreeNode(object):
  """Node of a Binary tree."""
  def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None):
    self.key = key
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

  def __str__(self):
    return "{0}".format(self.key)

def insert_left(parent, node):
  parent.left = node
  return parent  

def insert_right(parent, node):
  parent.right = node
  return parent

def is_leaf(node):
  """Checks whether given node is leaf."""
  return node.left is None and node.right is None

def is_full(node):
  """Checks if the subtree rooted at the given node is full.

  A Binary tree is full when every node other than leaves
  has two children.
  """
  if node is None:
    return True
  if is_leaf(node):
    return True
  if node.left is not None and node.right is not None:
    return is_full(node.left) and is_full(node.right)
  return False

def build_tree(inorder, preorder):
  """Builds a Binary Tree from given inorder and preorder traversal.
  Steps:
    1. Take the first element from the preorder list.
    2. Get the index of the element from inorder list.
    3. Set the element as root.
    4. Take all elements left to root from inorder list.
    5. Take all elements right to root from inorder list.
    6. Calculate preorder list for left and right subtree respectively.
    7. Repeat from step 1 for each subtree.
  """
  def recurse(node, inorder, preorder):
    if len(preorder) == 1:
      return TreeNode(preorder)
    key  = preorder[0]
    root_index    = inorder.find(key)
    inorder_left  = inorder[:root_index]
    inorder_right = inorder[root_index+1:]
    preorder_left = preorder[1:len(inorder_left)+1]
    preorder_right = preorder[root_index+1:]
    node = TreeNode(key)
    if len(inorder_left):
      insert_left(node, recurse(None, inorder_left, preorder_left))
    if len(inorder_right):
      insert_right(node, recurse(None, inorder_right, preorder_right))
    return node
  return recurse(None, inorder, preorder)



import unittest

class TestBinaryTree(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_isFull(self):
    root = build_tree('DBEAFIC', 'ABDEICF')
    self.assertTrue(is_full(root))

    root = build_tree('DBEAFC', 'ABDECF')
    self.assertFalse(is_full(root))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

#### Time Complexity

It seems its a \$O(N)\$ where \$N\$ is the number of nodes in the given Binary Tree.

I am also interested in mathematical approach for estimating complexity of these kind of problems. So, here is my initial approach:
\$T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + 2\$

Is there more cleaner way? Also, the above solution uses a DFS approach i.e. checking every node in a tree. Can we optimize it?

#### Note

I have extracted away the definition of `build_tree` as its not important here.

Comment: You could use breadth-first search, but I suggest you stick to the depth-first search. What comes to the time complexity, it is \$\Theta(N)\$ since you visit each node 3 times: (1) when descending from the parent node, (2) when returning from the left subtree, and (3) when returning from the right subtree. Another way of verifying the time complexity is to apply _the master theorem_, which for your recurrence whould, in fact, return \$\Theta(N)\$.

Comment: By removing the `build_tree()` you're also making it harder to run actual tests on your code... We now either have to make dry runs,  or build a tree of our own.

Comment: @holroy updated the code with `build_tree` method definition.

Comment: While you're at it, could you include `insert_left` and `insert_right` too?

Comment: @ferada added the missing definitions.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if you could use the attribute of full binary trees to improve your algorithm, this requires a notion of height (h) of the tree. You could then assert on the fact `if amount of nodes < 2h+1` its not a full binary tree. But I'm uncertain this is a good improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary tree here consists of either `None` or `TreeNode`, so all
functions should accept both of these objects as arguments, but
`is_leaf` currently breaks when passed a `None` node.  This
representation is also a bit problematic, because if you get a `None`
somewhere, how do you know it's meant to be a tree?

If that case is included, then the first check in `is_full` can be
removed.  Otherwise I don't see anything else to optimise, though the
results for checking the variables against for `None` could possibly be
cached so the code is minimally faster for huge trees.

Also,

- the indentation is inconsistent, `TreeNode` has four spaces in
  `__init__`.  You know,
  [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- `if len(x):` is less clear than, e.g. `if x:`, but in both cases it's
  relying on conversions from `int`/`list` to `bool`, so not very clear.

Comment: Basically `None` is considered full. Source: from wiki and Google.

Comment: Not what I meant. `None` should be handled in `is_leaf`, as in, if `None` is a valid tree, then functions working on trees shouldn't break when passed a tree.

Comment: Oh! you mean `if node is None: return False` I think.

Comment: One more thing, everything was working fine when I found that I need to keep track of the tree node somehow. Now, the things seems to get messy as I have to create a container class for the root. Every methods will be expecting `self` now, eewwww!